# How do I reduce integer A when integer B increments?

Tags: c#, integer

I am generally pretty new to C# and coding in general.
Basically, this is what I have.

```cs
public bool TimeLeft;

public void Process()
{
    int B = (int)Game.LocalPlayer.Character.TravelDistanceTo(spawnPoint) * 3; // An integer based on the distance of the character to a Vector3(spawnPoint).

    while (TimeLeft)
    {
        int A = Game.GameTime / 1000; //GameTime is time lapsed in game in milliseconds.
    }
           
}
```

But this is where my brain fries. Let's assume int B is 150.
How would I go about do reduce int B by 1 every time int A increases by 1? This happens within a loop.

I declare int B outside of the loop, and A inside because it needs to update every tick. TimeLeft is set somewhere else.

Comment: Are you attempting linear interpolation?

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of the value of A. When you poll A anew you store the value in another variable. Then you can compute the difference and decrease B by this difference. Pseudocode:

```
int A = ...
int B = ...

while(...)
{
  int A_new = ...
  B -= A_new - A;
}
```

Comment: I updated the main post, I realised I linked an older version of the code I was trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the values outside of the loop, inside the loop should only be the processing taking place. (Like Adok has mentioned)

I'd also say that `while (true)` is not a good practise of a general processing loop, unless you're making sure the whole program is defined within that loop.

Some game studios have a certain "Init" function, and an "Update" function, the init will happen when the game starts up the first time, and update will always be repeated like a loop after the init has been triggered. The benefit of using Update over a personal while loop is that it won't miss out out on other looping functions like Drawing

With understanding the difference between initialising and updating, It would be easier to understand a countdown like this:

In Init:

```
//defining 2 values to count down, one that decreases, and one that sets the value back to default.
int A = 150;
int Amax = A;
```

In Update:

```
if (A > 0) 
{
   A -= 1; //decrease the value if it's not at 0
} 
else
{
    //trigger an activity that happens when A reaches 0

    //reset the timer
    A = Amax;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I linked an old piece of code. I updated the main post. while (true) has already been replaced by TimeLeft. Sorry.

Comment: I see, though I notice that you're using a Game studio of some sorts (maybe XNA or Monogame? please specify in the tags!) So I do recommend understanding how the Update and Init functions behave, as that's a basic most game studios (if not all) have, maybe you won't even be in need of a Timer based loop.

Comment: Thanks! That is correct, it is a game engine. More specifically Rockstar Advanced Game Engine. It is a plugin, more specifically a MM:SS countdown timer. What I am trying to achieve is basically a countdown timer based on GameTime. Sometimes the game slows down so a millisecond in the script is not always a millisecond in game. So I base the timer on Game.GameTime which increments with game time passed. So while GameTime increases, I want another integer to decrease.